Anycubic X extruder dripping brown sludge
My Anycubic X extruder seems to have a nasty smell and brown sludge coming from a port where two wires/tubes interface to the head.
Could anyone help me diagnose this problem and what I should do? I’m pretty new to 3D printing!


Have you changed the nozzle before this incident?

Stop trying to print with Hershey's chocolate!

The "brown sludge" you are referring too is most likely excess filament that is leaking from your hotend past the heat break and the heating block.
In this case I would heat up the nozzle/block to 180 °C (because if there is a gap in between the heat break and the nozzle, you want it to be molten) and tighten the nozzle more secure to the heat break, not the heater block, if tightened incorrectly or nozzle against the heater block, this frequently leads to leaking filament:

(The image is uncredited as there are multiple sources without clear reference to the original, all credits go to the creator)
